# SQL Insert if not exists

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble trying to get this query to work, I've tried a ton of different approaches but non work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
INSERT INTO sessions (usr_id)
SELECT '46'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE usr_id = '46')
```

Comment: Just use insert ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MYSQL INSERT IGNORE:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (user_id) VALUES (46);
```

Comment: Tried that, and they still duplicated